# File truncated on upload to GCS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am uploading a relatively small(<1 MiB) .jsonl file on Google CLoud storage using the python API. The function I used is from the gcp documentation:

```
def upload_blob(key_path,bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name):
    """Uploads a file to the bucket."""
    # The ID of your GCS bucket
    # bucket_name = "your-bucket-name"
    # The path to your file to upload
    # source_file_name = "local/path/to/file"
    # The ID of your GCS object
    # destination_blob_name = "storage-object-name"

    storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(key_path)
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)

    blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)

    print(
        "File {} uploaded to {}.".format(
            source_file_name, destination_blob_name
        )
    )
```

The issue I am having is that the .jsonl file is getting truncated at 9500 lines after the upload. In fact, the 9500th line is not complete. I am not sure what the issue is and don't think there would be any limit for this small file. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you upload from an in-region service that averages 500 Mbps for its upload speed, the cutoff size for files is almost 2 GB. You may refer to the [upload size considerations](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploads-downloads#size) section.

Comment: Does your script print "File ... uploaded to ..."? Or does it crash before getting there?

Comment: It does print that and the script completes its run successfully. Also for the first comment, the file size is less than an MB so it is no where near that limit.

Comment: You can try uploading the file in chunks. You can find samples [here](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/97485/apiclient.http.MediaFileUpload). (search for request.next_chunk()). Let me know if that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem some time ago. In my case the upload to bucket was called inside a `with` python clause right after the line where I recorded contents to `source_file_name`, so I just needed to move the upload line outside the `with` in order to properly recorded and close local file to be uploaded.